# What way is better to use exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception

I have two ways for create exception.

The first way: I use base Exception class for create exception.

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        try
        {
            Method1ThrowException();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    public void Method1ThrowException()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

The second way: In this way I create User-Defined Exception class and then use this class for create exception.

```
public class Class2
{
    public void Method2()
    {
        try
        {
            Method2ThrowException();
        }
        catch (MethodException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    public void Method2ThrowException()
    {
        throw new MethodException();
    }
}

public class MethodException : Exception
{
    public MethodException()
    {

    }

    public MethodException(string message) : base(message)
    {

    }

    public MethodException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner)
    {

    }
}
```

What the difference between this ways use of exception?

I read that use the second way is better and I don't understand why? In both of ways I just create exceptions and get them.

Comment: "Better" is mostly opinion based. Both will do the same, bubble an exception through the call-stack. One will be BCL provided, one will be custom made by you. You may find this helpful when you create a 3rd party library and want to create exceptions that refer to your library code by wrapping them in a `MyFooLibraryException`.

Comment: Creating your own exception type is useful unless a BCL one is more appropriate.  Remember to [only catch exceptions you can handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229005(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Not really opinion based. Say you go to a restaurant, and you see "Food: $10". You order steak; they say "Sorry, we just have Food. Do you want some?" Me, I'd rather go to a restaurant that says on the menu what they serve; and I'd wager most people will agree with me.

Comment: @Amadan I'm glad you're hungry, but I think this question is more of a BCL exceptions vs custom exceptions. I don't think the OP really means "only use the general `Exception` type". Looks *to me* as if he's asking "is it better to create custom exceptions".

Comment: Code Analysis will issue a warning CA2201 for the first code snippet. So either define and throw your own exception or use an existing one such as InvalidOperationException as appropriate. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182338.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Now "I don't think the OP really means..." is truly a matter of opinion, since I can't see any evidence for that. He specifically says "I use base Exception class", and codes `throw new Exception()`. Raising specific pre-existing exceptions is fine if they fit the purpose; raising `Exception` pretty much never is.

Comment: @Amadan I agree, OP should clarify if he means "only use `Exception`"  or "use any out of the box provided exception".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way is better because you create your own exception type which can be suitable for specific situation. For example: you could create ConnectionBrokenException type when writing application which communicates over some network and throw it when connection is broken.

This gives you two main advantages:

**First**
You can handle exceptions in different ways depending on the exception type using try..catch block. You may decide to show message to user, rollback some operations or do other stuff.

```
try
{
    ... code throwing ConnectionBrokenException
}
catch(ConnectionBrokenException ex)
{
    _logger.LogError("Something bad has happened with connection", ex.Message);
}
catch(Exception)
{
    // handles other types of exceptions
}
```

**Second**
When analyzing logs from such application it is easier to diagnose some problems when each bad situation has its own exception. You can for example use some filtering to find only exception you're interested in.

Comment: thank you for your answer with an example. I got answer for my question.

Answer (score 2):

Because `catch (Exception e)` catches *everything*. There is no way to discriminate what kind of exception was raised. Thus, fine-grained error classes are good.

(Also, why define `Method1ThrowException`, instead of just `throw`ing the exception where it needs to be thrown? This just adds a useless layer to the stacktrace.)

Comment: thank you for your answer. The method `Method1ThrowException` it just example.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'better' way, as it depends on your specific needs.

If there is an existing exception type you can use, just use that one (`ArgumentException` etc). See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a list.

If you need special exception type, create your own, containing your own custom properties. Example:

```
 public BusinessException : Exception
 {
     public BusinessException(string reason)
     {
           Reason  = reason;
     }
     public string Reason {get; set;}
 }
```

If you are throwing these in a WCF service, be sure to add a global exception handler to map these exceptions to WCF faults. In case of web API, map them to HTML status.

Comment: thank you for your answer and thank you for your example. I will take note of your advice